Windows Server 2019 Enterprise CA Certificate Request Error
I'm setting up a Windows Server 2019 Enterprise CA for my lab.
I am setting up a Windows CA server so I can lab various things on my Palo Alto firewall that rely on certificate services.
I am not very familiar with Windows Server so need all the help I can get.
I setup Windows Server 2019 as an Enterprise CA.
When requesting a certificate using the web interface, the following error is displayed:
Error

Your request failed. An error occurred while the server was processing your request.

Contact your administrator for further assistance.

    Request Mode:
        newreq - New Request 
    Disposition:
        (never set) 
    Disposition message:
        (none) 
    Result:
        No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. 0x80070534 (WIN32: 1332 ERROR_NONE_MAPPED) 
    COM Error Info:
        CCertRequest::Submit: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. 0x80070534 (WIN32: 1332 ERROR_NONE_MAPPED) 
    LastStatus:
        No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. 0x80070534 (WIN32: 1332 ERROR_NONE_MAPPED) 
    Suggested Cause:
        No suggestions. 

I know this isn't best practice but this is for my homelab.
I want to be able to get certs signed and sub CAs too.
I have tried following the steps outlined here and that hasn't helped. I get the same error after enabling Everyone permissions applying to anonymous users.
I have also made sure that on both the templates and the CA itself that Everyone has the necessary permissions.
Please advise.
